# Get last login time of each User ID

Tags: mysql

How to get last login time of selected IDs?

Table

```
|  user_id  |  lastlogin
|  100      |  2016-03-05
|  110      |  2016-03-21
|  100      |  2016-03-29
|  100      |  2016-04-03
|  110      |  2016-04-02
```

Here is what I need:

```
|  user_id  |  lastlogin
|  100      |  2016-04-03
|  110      |  2016-04-02
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(lastlogin, '%d-%b-%Y') AS lastlogin,user_id
FROM last_logins
WHERE user_id IN (
100,110)
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY lastlogin DESC
```

If I use `GROUP BY`, it shows the old login record of `user_id`. If I use just `ORDER BY` it gives perfect results, but with multiple last logins of `user_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a simple `MAX`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(lastlogin), '%d-%b-%Y') AS lastlogin,
   user_id
FROM last_logins
WHERE user_id IN (100,110)
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY MAX(last_logins.lastlogin) DESC
```

Don't sort by the formatted `lastlogin` as this is not a date anymore.

Don't alias using an existing column name, this might lead to confusion and well-hidden bugs (the same condition in `WHERE` and `HAVING` meaning different things, for example).

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f793c/1) by jkavalik